# Decode to UTF-8 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

I have csv file with this content - as you can see some of field rows are not string values. I read the file using this command:

```
data = gpd.read_file('data.csv', encoding='utf8')
```

The CSV file:

[image: CSV file]

Notebook:

[image: Jupyter Notebook image]

As you can see, the `column name` is still not decoded. I have tried the following command, but it was not successful, because it sees the column as `str`, and can't call `decode()` function on it.

```
data['name'] = data['name'].apply(lambda x:x.decode('utf8', 'strict') if not isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Comment: It's not clear what the content of your CSV is, because the resentation may add the backslashes or they could be part of the actual data. Please extract a [mcve] (not pictures, people should be able to cut'n'paste the code) and use e.g. `hd`/`hexdump` or some other utility to give the bytewise content of a relevant portion of the file.

Comment: A data scientist is often forced to work with data in a terrible state.

Comment: Paste the content of the actual text-based CSV file, not a picture of it loaded into Excel.  It appears that the data in the file was actually written with `b'xxxx'` which is a problem in itself.  There are solutions, but I'm not going to manually type in your data to figure it out.  Paste text that we can copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works:

```
data['name'] = data['name'].apply(
    lambda x:x[2:-1].encode().decode("unicode_escape").encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode()
)
```

### Step by step

In:

```
x = r"b'\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb2\xd9\x87\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8'"
print(f"x {type(x)}\n\t= {x}\n")

x = x[2:-1]
print(f"x[2:-1] {type(x)}\n\t= {x}\n")

x = x.encode()
print(f"x[2:-1].encode() {type(x)}\n\t= {x}\n")

x = x.decode("unicode_escape").encode('raw_unicode_escape')
print(f"x[2:-1].encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape') {type(x)}\n\t= {x}\n")

x = x.decode()
print(f"x[2:-1].encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode() {type(x)}\n\t= {x}\n")
```

Out:

```
x <class 'str'>
    = b'\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb2\xd9\x87\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8'

x[2:-1] <class 'str'>
    = \xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb2\xd9\x87\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8

x[2:-1].encode() <class 'bytes'>
    = b'\\xd9\\x85\\xd9\\x86\\xd8\\xaa\\xd8\\xb2\\xd9\\x87\\xd8\\xb1\\xd8\\xa7\\xd8\\xa8'

x[2:-1].encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape') <class 'bytes'>
    = b'\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb2\xd9\x87\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8'

x[2:-1].encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode() <class 'str'>
    = منتزهراب
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works. If we are in the same city, I would invite you for a cup of coffee and a piece of cake. :)

Comment: Added a step-by-step section for a better understanding.

Comment: Simpler, from original `x`: `import ast; print(ast.literal_eval(x).decode())`